# CGridView change sorting method

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am new to Yii framework. I am analyzing autogenerated CRUD views. When I click column headers for sorting, it reloads data again, so it's much slower than writing jQuery way of sorting table. How to change that behavior. I do not want to reload data everytime I sort table, want to only sort what I have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort only the rows in the current page, not all rows in the results set? I'm not sure I see the use in this unless it's a fairly small results set. Most users will want to see the whole results set ordered by the column and not just the single page.

There's nothing built into `CGridView` to do it on the client I don't think, but it wouldn't be hard to write one

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var me = $(this)
    if ( me.find('.columnToCompare').text() > me.find('.secondColumn').text() )
    {
         me.prev().insertBefore(me);
    }
}
```

Very quickly typed up, but you get the gist hopefully.

Comment: Yes, I understood. You meant jQuery will sort only current page of table and it will be useless? Then that's OK. I misunderstood sort behavior of paginated data. Is it possible keep current dataset in memory that it could be get instantly when sorting for some time?

Comment: To be able to sort completely on the client you would have to retrieve **all** the records on the first load. Thats probably a lager performance problem than fetching from the server each time. There's nothing built in to Yii to do this because it's generally the least efficient way. If you're having performance issues fetching from the server, you should probably investigate and open a new question.